# mvn site creates only css,images and Web-Inf folder

Tags: java, maven

When I run mvn site:run and go to localhost:8080 i see only 3 folders:

- css
- images
- Web-Inf

How do I get the index.html file? or where should i create an index.html?

`pm.xml` in `site/`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <port>9000</port>
          <tempWebappDirectory>
            ${basedir}/src/documentation/src/site
          </tempWebappDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: `<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" ....
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <port>9000</port>
          <tempWebappDirectory>${basedir}/src/documentation/src/site</tempWebappDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
`  due to the limited number of char i can' show everything sorry

Comment: Could you please edit your question and include it all in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following project structure could work for you:

```
<project>
   +- src/
      +- site/
          +- apt/
          |   +- apt-files 
          |   +- index.apt            <-- index file
          |    
          |- fml/                     <-- optional ... 
          |   +- fml-files
          |
          |- ....
          |   +- ...
          |
          |- resources/
          |   +- css/
          |   +- images/
          |    
          `- site.xml                 <-- this must be configuered appropriately
```

Also configure the following to be able to deploy:

```
  <distributionManagement>
     <site>
       <id>site</id>
       <url>http://host.coom/site</url>
     </site>
  </distributionManagement>
```

Comment: now it works..i had to create the folder "resources"... but what is the url for deploying? i dont have a website...can i just remove the distribution management?